# Light as child of camera but Y position is fixed to scene?

Tags: three.js

Like the title, Is that possible? And how can i do that?

I want the spotLight's moving X and Z position follow the camera. Y position is still fixed to scene.

I tried this:

```
spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
camera.add( spotLight );

....

function animate() {
    spotLight.position.y = scene.position.y + 800;

    request = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    render();
}
```

But all XYZ position of the spotLight still moving with camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible as a child object. Matrices of child objects are relative to matrices of their's parents. I suppose you could try to move spotlight with camera without making light camera's child.

```
spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );

// ....

function animate() {
  spotLight.position = camera.position.clone();
  spotLight.position.y = scene.position.y + 800;

  request = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  render();
}
```